# Check Label in email and delete specific ones

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, email, foreach

I have this code that is suppose to check each label for the word "closed", and after its done checking it will remove all the text that is in the labels and place everything thats NOT labeled "closed" into the TO section of an email. I dont know what im doing wrong but it doesnt work. Any suggestions?

```
foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
            if (c is Label)
            {
                // Grab label
                Label lbl = c as Label;
                if (lbl.Text.Contains("closed"))
                {
                    lbl.Text.Replace("closed", "");
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you forgot to assign the modified text value, because `Replace()` method returns replaced text as return value:

```
lbl.Text = lbl.Text.Replace("closed", "");
```

But there might be more problems with your code, it's not very clear how is your problem related to emails.

Answer (score 0):

Initially take your input (i.e. label list in a List)

```
 List<string> TotalLabels = GetAllLabels();
    for (int i = 0; i < TotalLabels.Count; i++)
    {
    if (TotalLabels[i].Contains("closed"))
    {
    TotalLabels.RemoveAt(i);
    i--;
    }
    }
```

Now you have a final list which you wanted removing "closed".

Comment: Awesome! One last question, GetAllLabels do i have to declare them? I get an error on it. Thank yoU!!

Comment: You will have to write a method named GetAllLabels and call it in the above condition.The method will return all label name currently present out of which you wish to filter out the labels containing "closed" text.